# Change name of predicate/functor in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a module which uses [`term_expansion/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_expansion/2) to process a prolog source file. While doing so, I deconstruct predicates using [`=..`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) or project to its name using [`functor/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=functor/3).
For example:

```
?- functor(pred(foo, bar), N, _).
N = pred.

?- pred(foo, bar) =.. L.
L = [pred, foo, bar].
```

Now I want to change the name of `pred` to (for example) `pred_expanded` and make it a term again, so that `pred(foo, bar)` becomes `pred_expanded(foo, bar)`.

I tried `append(pred, "_expanded", F)` and `append(pred, '_expanded', F)` without success.

Comment: Use the ISO predicate **`atom_concat/3`** to concatenate atoms.

Comment: @mat Why don't you write an answer? And what would happen if there happens to exist a predicate in the same module with the "expanded" name? (I realize this is a more general problem with generating code with `term_expansion/2`). And was it so that the expansion happens in a single pass, that is, expanded code is not subject to further expansion automatically, even if there is an expansion defined for it?

Comment: @Boris: I would like to attract more posters to this question, which I think is a good entry point to many important topics such as meta-programming, term expansion etc. If I simply answer "use atom_concat/3" and this gets immediately accepted, then the whole question will soon be forgotten and it is unlikely that other important and related things, such as you mentioned, will still be discussed at this opportunity. Nevertheless, I also would like to help users with their more immediate problems, so I think a short comment is best to satisfy both requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
change_functor(Term,NewFunctor,NewTerm) :-
    Term =.. [_|Args],
    NewTerm =.. [NewFunctor|Args].

term_expansion(Term,ExpandedTerm) :-
    functor(Term,pred,2),
    change_functor(Term,pred_expanded,ExpandedTerm).
```

For example:

```
?- term_expansion(pred(foo,bar),T).
T = pred_expanded(foo, bar).
```

Illustrates how to use the "univ" predefined predicate. However, this is the best solution:

```
term_expansion(pred(A,B),pred_expanded(A,B)).
```

If you need to translate **any** functor, use atom_concat/3 as stated before:

```
term_expansion(Term,ExpandedTerm) :-
    functor(Term,F,_),
    atom_concat(F,'_expanded',NewF),
    change_functor(Term,NewF,ExpandedTerm).
```

Example:

```
?- term_expansion(kk(1,2,3),N).
N = kk_expanded(1, 2, 3).
```